# Combining output of many objects into a CSV

Tags: powershell

I'd like to take specific output of four objects and put them into a CSV.

```
$obj1 = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select-object name,manufacturer,model,totalphysicalram
$obj2 = get-wmiobject win32_processor | select-object deviceid,name,maxclockspeed,numberofcores
$obj3 = get-wmiobject win32_bios | select-object serialnumber
$obj4 = get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | select-object osarchitecture
```

I'd like to combine all of those into the same output row in a csv.

How can I do this with powershell?  Should I build an array of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fault you for not having a start on this, I wouldn't have had any idea where to go with code a year ago myself. Try this out and see how it strikes you...

```
$obj1 = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select-object name,manufacturer,model,TotalPhysicalMemory
$obj2 = get-wmiobject win32_processor | select-object deviceid,@{l="Proc";e={$_.name}},maxclockspeed,numberofcores
$obj3 = get-wmiobject win32_bios | select-object serialnumber
$obj4 = get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | select-object osarchitecture

$Combined = New-Object -Type PSObject
$obj1,$obj2,$obj3,$obj4|%{$CurObj = $_;$_|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "NoteProperty"}|%{$NewMember = $_.Name;$Combined|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $NewMember -Value $CurObj.$NewMember}}
```

I fixed TotalPhysicalMemory (not totalphysicalram), and changed the proc query so it renamed the Name property to Proc, that way you don't have 2 properties with the same name. Then I fed all 4 objects into a ForEach loop, and for each object I got it's members and filtered for the NoteProperty members (getting rid of Methods and what not). For each one I took the member's name and created a property in a new PSCustomObject that I had created with that same name, and assigned the value from the original object associated with that property. I hope that makes sense, I found it a little hard to follow and I wrote the thing...

**Edit:** Dur... I didn't answer the original question, I just got all the prep work done. Here's how you output it:

```
$Combined|Export-CSV -Path C:\SomeFolder\MachineSpecs.CSV -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  For future reference, adding arbitrary strings is quite easy as well, for instance: `$obj1 = new-object system.object; $obj1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "date" -Value $(get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 2):

I tried running TheMadTechnician's answer on PSv3 and it didn't like the Out-CSV cmdlet. So I replaced it with Export-CSV and it worked fine.

```
$obj1 = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select-object name,manufacturer,model,TotalPhysicalMemory
$obj2 = get-wmiobject win32_processor | select-object deviceid,@{l="Proc";e={$_.name}},maxclockspeed,numberofcores
$obj3 = get-wmiobject win32_bios | select-object serialnumber
$obj4 = get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem | select-object osarchitecture

$Combined = New-Object -Type PSObject
$obj1,$obj2,$obj3,$obj4|%{$CurObj = $_;$_|gm|?{$_.MemberType -match "NoteProperty"}|%{$NewMember = $_.Name;$Combined|Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $NewMember -Value $CurObj.$NewMember}}
$Combined | Export-CSV -Path H:\MachineSpecs.CSV -NoTypeInfo
```

Gives the output of:
"manufacturer","model","name","TotalPhysicalMemory","deviceid","maxclockspeed","numberofcores","Proc","serialnumber","osarchitecture"
"Hewlett-Packard","HP EliteBook 8760w","LAUCA-44A135","8537874432","CPU0","2201","4","Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz","USH244A135","64-bit"

Comment: Yep, you're right. That's not a good command, good catch. I'll update my answer to reflect your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a readable syntax I like for this task, hope this helps.  This creates a hashtable of properties and adds it to a PSObject, then adds that to an array.  You can do as you wish with the resulting array.  I typically run this in a foreach loop against a list of remote computers.  You can glom together all kinds of disparate data for reporting very easily this way.

```
$Results = @()

$obj1 = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem 
$obj2 = get-wmiobject win32_processor
$obj3 = get-wmiobject win32_bios
$obj4 = get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem

  $Obj = new-object psobject -property@{
       PropertyName = $Obj2.Property
       SomeOtherPropertName = $obj1.Property
       SerialNumber = $obj3.SerialNumber
       DateCollected = (get-date).DateTime
       OSArchitecture = $obj4.OsArchitecture
  }

$Results+=$obj
```